# Veeva Salesforce uploading presentation

Tags: salesforce

maybe this is not a good quetion posted on this site, but I am trying to upload a presentation to SalesForce (https://test.salesforce.com/). I understand that at first I have to create "Key messages" which represent each slides in the presentation, then I create new CLM presentation and select presentation slides.

But then I am stucked. Is this everything to uploading the presentation or I have to migrate the presentation somewhere, upload somewhere else using FTP, etc.

I hope my question is understandable (because my English is not very good).
Thanks for help.

Comment: You'll really need to add more detail. How are you trying to upload ? In the webinterface ? api ? upload to what  .. chatter, content, file, document.. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, follow these steps to upload a presentation with single slide..

1. Create a Key message and upload the media (zip file). (Simply give key message name and upload proper *well-formed* zip)
2. Create a Presentation Slide (Just slide name)
3. Now, create a CLM Presentation, in which you need to browse and select the above 2 objects against their respective fields.

That's it on salesforce.

Now *sync* iRep app on device/iPad and it should come down in "Media".

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**1.Create a new presentation**

**2.Go to CLM Key Messages** tab and here, before creating a new key message you might need to create a new view("*Create New View*" link button) to group these key messages(at least that's how I do it).
Here you need to make sure that the filter method is set correctly otherwise I won't be able to see those key messages attached to this view.
So you can set sth like this(on step 2):

**Field  | Operator | Value**

Message | contains | slide_prefix

On step 3 you need to add "Message" in "Selected fields" Tab

**3.Now create a "New CLM Message"** and make sure that it has "slide_prefix" on his name composition(Ex: if slide_prefix is "EXSlide" then clm message should be named like: EXSlide myslide01 or EXSlide_slide01)

**4.After creating CLM key message** you will be redirected to his info page where you need to upload the ".zip" file.

**5.Last step** is to create "*New Presentation Slide*"(On the bottom of the page). Here you need to input the Presentation(presentation name created on step 1), key message name(you can search for them) and a display order

Now sync the ipad and it should appear.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to sTx answer, you can take a look at the "Veeva Content Creation Guidelines" (Link below). This will fit most of your developer needs.

[Veeva Content Creation Guidelines](https://crmhelp.veeva.com/doc/Content/Print-only_topics/CLM%20Content%20Creation%20Guide.pdf)

Keep in mind that often client groups have special region codes and labeling rules (see also: sTx answer to "Prefix" rules), that you have to follow, to match users and contents in a global account. If you dont, nothing will appear on the iPad. Example: yourID + Language + Country (YourID_ENG_UK.zip)

Also companys often split thier environment in two, a sandbox and a production section - Make sure you have the permission to see sandbox contents. For this purpose, activate the "Training Content" checkbox on the presentation object, to see your presentation without a migration.

All contents you create in the backend are by default visible to you on the iPad. Check the "Config" > "Media" list and look for your Zips files; if they get downloaded.